# my website is working at all browsers but not at firefox?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

i made new design and this website works fine with all browser expect Firefox, i can't Apply the Css file.

i tried to insert the style directly to the page and it didn't work.
i tried to insert the style at style.css and it didn't work.
i tried every possible thing i know so i guess someone can help me here

this design located here : http://descod.net/HTML/AD/

it works with Google chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer and even Safari.

Thanks

Comment: which version of firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an AD in all of you urls path which means that adblock is gonna try and block it.

Your website doesn't work on my chrome because I have addblock but is fine on my firefox

Comment: this is the last version 43.0.2

Comment: Good point Thank you.

ADblock is blocking every file with AD "Which is the name of this file" i tried to Change it to Other name and it works.

Thanks